# phpcs в Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-code

В VS Code постоянно всплывает это уведомление

> phpcs: Unable to locate phpcs. Please add phpcs to your global path or use composer depency manager to install it in your project locally

Что это значит?

Answer (score 0):

phpCS - PHP СodeSniffer - расширение "vscode-phpcs" - если вы его не используете (пока), его можно просто удалить из установленных расширений и ошибка пропадёт.